# Restart a WCF service hosted by a C# console application

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service that is hosted on a c# console application. Is there a way to restart this service, preferably by calling an endpoint in the service itself (ex. myService.Restart()).

Thanks

Comment: You mean send the command from a client _to_ the host? Even if you could do such a thing, this is analogous to `C:\> format c:`. If you are hosting _in_ a console application (I believe you are mistaken), then restarting the application ought to do the trick.

Comment: How can I restart the host application from a remote machine. The wcf service lives in a win7 machine.

Comment: Can't you just expose a service method which carries out the process that _would_ occur when the application is restarted (i.e. reloads the files)? As opposed to forcing a restart in order for it to happen.

Comment: The files are locked by the service (I'm doing Assembly.Load(some nunit dll files).

Comment: So, the service _is_ hosted in a console application? Is this a peer-to-peer service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my question, I have solved the problem by doing the following:

- Separating the code that loads the DLL files from the WCF service code into another class library project
- Create an interface with the same method signatures as the ones that load DLL files in the new project (this interface is used by both projects now)
- In the web service, load the other project in a new application domain. This way the DLL files are locked by the new application domain not the default.

If I want to update my nunit DLL files now, all I have to do is unload the application domain from the web service, update the files and finally create a new application domain.

```
AppDomain remoteDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("New Domain");
IClass1 class1 = (IClass1)remoteDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(
                           "Test1.dll", "Test1.Class1");
```

Note: IClass1 is the common interface between the projects.

Comment: I know it's 4 years ago, but can you provide an example to the whole solution? I don't fully understand how to implement your approach. please correct me if I'm wrong - it seems to me that you haven't restarted the **WCF service** itself, but actually restarted WCF Service 'Plugins'; by utilizing each DLL Plugin in it's own AppDomain.

Comment: I'm not the original poster, but my interpretation is that by shutting down and recreating the app domain he is restarting the service, but not the console application which hosts the service.

Answer (score 1):

I have to do something similar when I perform an automatic update of a remote WCF service. In your Restart() method, close the host:

```
    try
    {
        host.Description.Endpoints.Where(x => !x.Address.ToString().EndsWith("MEX")).ForEach(endpoint => _log.InfoFormat("Closing {0}", endpoint.Address));
        host.Close(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        host.Abort();
    }
```

I wait for my update to apply, and then after a success or failure, I re-open the host using the same code I used to start it in the first place.

If you just wanted to restart immediately, you could just call host.Open(), or you could set up a timer to call it, etc.

```
try
{
    host.Open();
    host.Description.Endpoints.Where(x => !x.Address.ToString().EndsWith("MEX")).ForEach(endpoint => _log.InfoFormat("Host opened at: {0}", endpoint.Address));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _log.Error("Unable to open host.", ex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you definitely are not going to be able to 'restart' a faulted service from calling that same service itself. In theory you could host 2 services in the same process. put the one you want to be 'restartable' in a public static variable and restart it within the other service. The problem would be restarting the restarter service if it faults... :) and you definitely want 'administrator-like' restrictions on your restarter service so unauthorized users can't do it.

Comment: The service is not faulted, it just has outdated files that needs to be updated from a network share. I could make the service to get the most updated files from network share every time its used (when any endpoint is called) but that is inefficient. Thus why I want to create an endpoint (restart) that would restart the service (I don't need to restart the host application (c# console app))

Comment: One more thing I can't update the files without restarting the service because it locks the files (nunit dll files)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit kludgy, but I suppose you could expose a callback on your service that the host could attach to and take appropriate action when it's triggered.  That would give your host the ability to decide what a "restart" really means and how it needs to be executed.  More importantly, it lets your decide whether it should do something extreme like spawn off a watcher process and then off itself or gracefully trash and reinstantiate your service (preferable).

Mmmmmm... kludge....

Answer (score 0):

You cannot ask a service to restart itself. Consider a windows service (a service hosted in windows provided container) which has a RESTART functionality. Here RESTART functionality is provided not by the service but by the container. The container controls how to stop the service and start it.

Similarly in your case, you should try to look out for options if your container can provide the functionality you need. Since you want to control it remotely, the container should also be available remotely, which cannot be possible if the container is a console application. Instead it has to be another web service or web application.

Comment: I believe the OP is talking about restarting the WCF service, not the host application. This is possible by closing the WCF host and opening it again. If you want a super ugly hack, not recommended, I once had to have a remote service restart, and I accomplished it by setting the windows service restart options to restart on failure, and then called Environment.Exit(-1) in the service. Windows saw it as a crash and restarted it. Ugly, and not recommended, but in this one far edge case, it solved a real problem.